# How to call dynamic form id in ajax

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a marketplace assign product if same product have more then 1 seller it display that seller's information as well as product information with Add to cart. I am using ajax add to cart

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl(Mage::registry('current_product')); ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form1_<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId(); ?>">

<button id="<?php echo $seller->getMpassignproductId() ?>"  class="button btn-cart customaddtocart" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart')?>">
    <span>
    <span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Bag')?></span></span></button><div>
    <button class="button buy-now" onclick="location.href ='{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}/checkout/cart/add?product=1&qty=1'">
    <span><span>Buy Now</span></span></button></div>



</form>
```

Here My Js

```
if(el.up('form#product_addtocart_form1')){
                    var url =   $('product_addtocart_form1').readAttribute('action');
                    var link = url.replace('checkout','ajaxcart').replace('wishlist/index','ajaxcart/wishlist').replace('https','http');                    
                    el.onclick = function(){
                        if(productAddToCartForm.submit){
                            var emajcForm = productAddToCartForm;
                            if (('undefined' != typeof productAddToCartFormOld) && productAddToCartFormOld)
                                emajcForm   =   productAddToCartFormOld;
                            if(emajcForm.validator && emajcForm.validator.validate()){
                                jQuery('#product_addtocart_form1').ajaxForm(options);
                                $('product_addtocart_form1').setAttribute("action", link);
                                jQuery('#product_addtocart_form1').submit();
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```

My Problem is how to pass this dynamic id into that ajax

My form id like this way `product_addtocart_form1_187`
**187** is a product id it will change based on product id

How to call please suggest me?

Comment: is form name fixed?

Comment: yes form name is fixed product_addtocart_form1

Comment: check this link inspect http://kidsdial.com/peacock-bebe-blocks-set-no-7.html

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this

```
<script>
$(document).delegate('form', 'submit', function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var id = $form.attr('id');
    var data = $form.serialize();
    // ...
});
</script>
```

Comment: How to use that dynamic id here

Comment: can you please explain this